# Want to display .php file as without extension?

Tags: php, apache

my url is :http://www.example.com/home.php i want to show it when enduser navigates my site as http://www.example.com/home. I know this can be done through .htaccess file.

```
Following is the htacces file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

Nothing is happening with the above code in .htaccess file.I want to show entire site pages without .php extension.Can anyone suggest me how to do this

Comment: Check if you have enabled processing of .htaccess files. You have access to the log files? oh, and, just to make sure: where is that .htaccess file located?

Comment: Please use the search function. One of many dublicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498410/short-url-system-how-to-redirect-the-custom-urls

Comment: Be careful of duplicate content, you're going to want to add a rule to physically redirect users to the non-extension version

Comment: i think (.+)$, try replacing it and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```